# Calculating net wins for football teams

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, data-science

As part of a machine learning architecture I'm building I need to parallelise a certain calculation in pytorch. For simplicity I'm going state a modified version of the problem and use numpy so it's easier to understand.

Suppose I have a collection of football teams (say 10) and they play a collection of matches (say 20). Each football team is represented by an ID (a number from 1-10). The match outcomes are saved as tuples `(t_1, t_2, win)` where `t_i` is the ID (int) for 'team i', and win=1 if team 1 wins (win=-1 if team 2 wins).

I want to calculate the total number of wins for every team. More specifically I want an numpy array `X` (of shape (10)) where `X[t_i]` := wins - losses (of 'team i' from the 20 matches). Assuming the match data is split into numpy arrays `match` (of shape (20, 2)), and `outcome` (of shape (20,1)), my current solution for solving this problem is as follows

```
outcome = np.concatenate((outcome, -outcome), axis=1)
for i in range(20):
    X[match[i]] += outcome[i]
```

Now as you can guess, I want to get rid of the for loop. If I was to replace this code with

```
X[match] += outcome
```

Then clearly the it will not work. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem completely in parallel? Like I said, my problem is actually more complicated than what I've stated here. It's closer to wanting to calculate the win/loss total for each player on each team. If possible could someone provide a solution which is not dependant on there only being two teams in each match. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `X[match] += outcome`

Comment: @JayMody Unfortunely while this solution is the obvious one, it doesn't work. The problem is that as the same team can be present in different games, the same index must there be updated multiple times. This is not allowed when using ```X[match]```. Don't worry though, I managed to solve it another way! Thanks -L

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who sees this, I figured out a solution using 'scatter' in pytorch however it is a bit ad-hoc. Here is the equivalent code for numpy.

```
outcome = np.concatenate((outcome, -outcome), axis=1)
temp = np.put_along_axis(np.zeros((20, 10)), match, outcomes, 1)
scores = np.sum(temp, axis=0)
```